# Embedded Google Apps Script to search for and collect a copy of files in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Embedded Google Apps Script**

I've written an embedded Google Apps script to advanced search Google drive for files matching search parameters supplied in the hosting spreadsheet.

**Link to Google sheets with embedded script : [collect_files](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gyKonFrpMe9RYQ5X0HmnR_6eab6fwsZJwIQ51a_esr8/edit?usp=sharing)**

The script works as intended - I've tested in a private Google drive and Workspace environment - but I'm sure the code is far from optimal. I'd appreciate any feedback from Javascript or Google Apps Script experts alike.

**Main function to search for and copy files** (bound to button)

```
function collect_files() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // Grab settings from spreadsheet
  var mediatype = ss.getRangeByName("list_mediatype").getValue();
  var search = ss.getRangeByName("list_search").getValue();
  var collection_folder_id = ss.getRangeByName("list_collection_folder_id").getValue();
  var collected_prefix = ss.getRangeByName("list_collected_prefix").getValue();
  var limit = ss.getRangeByName("list_limit").getValue();
  var shared_with_me = ss.getRangeByName("list_shared_with_me").getValue();
  var list = ss.getRangeByName("list_results");

  // Clear the results range
  if(!list.isBlank()){
    var result = ui.alert("STOP!","There are still results in this sheet. Continuing with clear the list. Are you ok with that? If you click 'Cancel', you can copy the existing results to a new sheet if you like.",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if(result == ui.Button.CANCEL){
      return;
    }
  }
  list.clear();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var row = list.getRow(); // Start of the range.

  // Check collection folder exists
  try{
    var collection_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(collection_folder_id);
  } catch(e){
    ui.alert("Whoops!","Sorry, the collection folder ID seems to be wrong. Check it and try again.",ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    return;
  }

  // Set up variables for script
  var query = "title contains '" + search + "' " 
            + "and not '" + collection_folder_id + "' in parents "
            + "and trashed=false "
            + "and not mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"; // Exclude folders
  if(collected_prefix.length > 1){
    query = query + " and not title contains '" + collected_prefix + "' ";
  }
  if(mediatype.length > 1){
    query = query + " and mimeType = '"+mediatype+"'";
  }

  // Actually perform the search!
  var search = Drive.Files.list( // This will also return items 'shared with me'.
  {
    corpora: "allDrives",
    includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, 
    supportsAllDrives: true, 
    maxResults: 1000, 
    q: query
  }).items;

  // Clean up search results for shared files and limit
  var found = [];
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;

  while(j <= limit-1 && i <= search.length-1){
    if(search[i].parents.length == 0){ // I think this is a good indicator of shared files
      if(shared_with_me){
        found.push(search[i]);
        j++;
      }
    } else {
      found.push(search[i])
      j++;
    }
    i++;
  }

  // Now do the copy, if there are any results to copy
  if(found.length > 0){
    var result = ui.alert("Continue?","I'm going to copy "+found.length+" item(s). This operation cannot be undone. Is this OK?",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if(result == ui.Button.CANCEL){
      return;
    } else {
      found.forEach(e => {
        var item = DriveApp.getFileById(e.id);
        var drive_mime_type = item.getMimeType();
        // var file_name = item.getName();
        if(e.parents.length > 0){ // This file has parents
          var parent = item.getParents().next();
          var parent_folder_name = parent.getName();
          var parent_folder_link = parent.getUrl();
          var parent_folder_id   = parent.getId();
          var parent_folder_tree = get_folder_tree(parent_folder_id,[parent_folder_name]).reverse().join(" > ");
          var parent_folder_cell = '=HYPERLINK("'+parent_folder_link+'","'+parent_folder_tree+'")'
        } else {
          var parent_folder_cell = 'File has no parents (probably shared)';
        }

        var copy = item.makeCopy(collection_folder); // Make a copy and grab the object.

        try{ // Might not be able to rename shared files
          if(copy.getMimeType().startsWith("application/vnd.google-apps.")){ // It's a Google document
            copy.setName(copy.getName().slice(8)); // Remove 'copy of' from beginning of copy filename for Google files
          }
        } catch(error) {
          var shared = true; // Don't need this but have to have something in the catch
        }

        try{ // Might not be able to rename shared files
          item.setName(collected_prefix + item.getName());
        } catch(error) {
          var shared = true; // Don't need this but have to have something in the catch
        }

        var data = [[
          '=HYPERLINK("'+copy.getUrl()+'","'+copy.getName()+'")',
          drive_mime_type,
          parent_folder_cell,
          '=HYPERLINK("'+item.getUrl()+'","'+item.getName()+'")',
        ]]
        ss.getRange("A"+row+":D"+row).setValues(data);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        row += 1;
      });
    }
  } else {
    ui.alert("Nowt!","I can't find anything with those search parameters. Change them and try again if you like.",ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    return;
  }
  ui.alert("Done!","That's it. Copies of all the files I found are in the collection folder and all the originals are marked with the collection prefix.",ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  return;
}
```

**Helper function to generate folder path to original file**

```
// Funky little recursive function to populate the folder tree.
function get_folder_tree(folder_id,tree=[]){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id);
  var parent = folder.getParents();
  if(parent.hasNext()){
    var next_parent = parent.next();
    tree.push(next_parent.getName());
    get_folder_tree(next_parent.getId(),tree);
  }
  return tree;
}
```

**Function to copy results to new sheet** (bound to button)

```
// Copy results to new sheet
function copy_results(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var new_sheet = ss.insertSheet();
  var name = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
  new_sheet.setName(name);
  var results_range = ss.getRangeByName('list_results');
  var results = results_range.getValues();
  results_range.copyTo(new_sheet.getRange(1,1,results.length,results[0].length));
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  ui.alert("Done.","Your results have been copied to a new sheet.",ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```